# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, android-toolbar

I am getting a weird issue

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder

mainly on `4.2.2` and `4.4.2` devices. It happened when I started using supportv7 library in my application code to take the advantage of material designs TOOLBAR.

Here are my `build.gradle` dependencies:

```
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

        compile files('libs/sinch-android-verification-1.0.4.jar')
        compile project(':library')
        compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.2@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }

        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.6.0'
        compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.0.2'
        compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.horizontallistview:hlistview:1.2.2'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
        compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:1.8.8'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.github.freshdesk:hotline-android:1.0.+'
        //compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
}
```

Can anyone please help. I am stuck since 2 days back on the same. I have checked various proguard fixes but had a bad luck with that too. Please help

Answer (score 1):

See this issue on Google Discussion.

As [#150 from google groups](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78377#c150) said

> Because careful with -keep class
>   !android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.**. There are a number of
>   classes in there which are referenced from the appcompat's resources.

The better solution is add the following lines instead:

```
-keep class !android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.*MenuBuilder*, android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

Comment: @StanislavParkhomenko It has not worked for me. Already checked the same.

Comment: @StanislavParkhomenko Can we use both support v4 and appcompat in dependencies.. both ?

Comment: @GauravArora This is solve the issue in `Android 4.2` device But it again come out in `Api 23.0` .

Comment: @GauravArora I guess yes. That hack with proguard didnt help me as well when I stuck with that problem.

Comment: The only way I can see in that situation - using both v7 & v4 support library, and downgrade lower then 23.0 library. Because google guys told that its not bug in their library but in manufacturer code. Nuffsaid.

Comment: @StanislavParkhomenko You are Right and it mainly in `Samsung` manufacturer code.

Comment: @Ironman yeah, I know :).  Plus some rainbow and other chinees devices.

Comment: @Ironman Its available in Techno too. So what version of appcompat library should I use to get a bug free apk ? Please suggest

Comment: @GauravArora I suggest you only one best solution is too check all discussion on the google group and suggestion and pick up best one.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked for me and it took 2 weeks to find this solution:

Changed build tools to:

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```

and replaced

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
```

with

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'

compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:24.2.1'
```